# CSS - Double size <img> inside <p>

Tags: html, css

I'm using `<img>` tags inside `<p>` tags for display mathematical formulas, like below:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor, <img src="my-crazy-formula.svg">, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

However, the formulas appear small when I open the file, so I tried to increase their size by using `transform: scale(2);`.

Unfortunately, it brought another problem: the CSS transformations do not affect the box model, so I tried to use margins, but they only work well if the formulas are short.

So my question is: How can I (via CSS only) increase the size of a `<img>` tag inside a `<p>` or `<li>`?

PS: I'm using this for a ebook so using something like `height: 100px` will not work well. And my HTML is autogenerated from a Markdown file.

Comment: @Doorknob Nice guess, but [no](http://jsfiddle.net/v4m387zw/). (And no, too, to `width:200%`.)

Comment: Gross-solution: use JS to post-load process the images and double their dimensions.

Comment: Is a fixed-height acceptable if it does not use `px` units, e.g. `height:1cm`? Are you sure that a fixed height is not acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works in all the browsers/environments you care about, I would use:

```
p img, li img { zoom:2 }
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v4m387zw/2/

---

Failing that, I think the easiest would be to use jQuery and just post-resize them. For example (untested):

```js
$(function(){
   $('p img, li img').each(function(){
     var $img = $(this);
     $img.height($img.height()*2); // assumes width not set
   });
});
```

If all elements are the same height (as I imagine they might be for inline formulae) then you could make this slightly simpler and more efficient with:

```js
$(function(){
   var imgs = $('p img, li img');
   imgs.height(imgs.height()*2); // assumes width not set
});
```

Comment: @gjvnq Your'e welcome. Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you feel that this answer fully solved your question, please click the check mark next to it to reward me, and—more importantly—to help others in the future with the same problem find a good solution.

Comment: RE "works in all the browsers/environments you care about"...I care about Firefox. And Safari (but less so).

Answer (score -1):

You could try change the width instead by using a '%'.

```
img{
    height: auto;
    width: 22%; /* or what ever you want it to be */
}
```

Comment: This would cause images to resize as their parent container changes its width, e.g. if the window is resized horizontally.